# VPN between Google Compute Engine and Oracle Compute Cloud Service

Tags: vpn

Last time we failed trying to connect our VPN (on GCE) to one of our client's VPN gateway on Oracle compute.
Creating the gateways and tunnels on both system is pretty straightforward, and there are not many options to go around.

On google's vpn logs, we can see NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN events being thrown, and the troubleshooting section specifically says "If the VPN logs indicate error no-proposal-chosen, this indicates that there was no match between the algorithms configured on the pair of VPN gateways. In IKEv1, the set of algorithms must be a complete match. In IKEv2, there must be one common algorithm between the two configurations."

I would like to confirm that connecting from GCE to Oracle Compute is indeed impossible.
Being quite illiterate on VPN's and networking , I'm not sure how I should proceed to check this.

This link details GCE's vpn support : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/advanced

And this one Oracle's vpn support :
http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/stcomputecs/STCSG/GUID-07FAD4A9-DDE4-4391-BB9C-EA4784552EDA.htm#STCSG-GUID-2B3CD305-F346-4A4E-94A2-B88244BFB3D4

Comment: The issue I think is that both VPN options are conceived for connecting as a "client" that is on your premises allowing to reach your cloud instances securely. You are looking to connect two cloud services, which probably fail as the preset configurations of each one (GCE and Corente) are unlikely to match.

Is it an option for you to have a bridge? I mean, a 3rd node that speaks to each cloud provider using the intended parameters, and moves traffic between them? It can be a cloud instance, or a server on your premises.

Comment: Could you share a tcpdump with the proposals? You can do this, configuring an instance as remote peer and executing a tcpdump in the instance to check the traffic.